# What does JSON_ERROR_RECURSION mean from json_encode?

Tags: php, php-7

I get this error on PHP7 every about 100 requests for some odd reason and I cannot get rid of it until I restart the fpm demon, however, the real problem is I cannot explain what the error is to start diagnosing this.

I took a look at the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php which was not very useful and there does not seem to be any real links hanging about.

I know this error is not actually related to recursion depth (`JSON_ERROR_DEPTH`) so what does this error actually mean?

This is the `var_dump()` of the array that is failing:

```
 array (
'ns' => 'user',
'where' => '{"_id":"MongoDB\\\\BSON\\\\ObjectID(5505a4f647ac1824618b4567)","status":10}',
'projection' =>
array (
),
'sort' =>
array (
),
'limit' => NULL,
'skip' => NULL,
)
```

Comment: JSON_ERROR_RECURSION (integer)

    The object or array passed to json_encode() include recursive references and cannot be encoded. If the JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR option was given, NULL will be encoded in the place of the recursive reference.

    This constant is available as of PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: Sorry if you've already done it (you don't really say) but if you log data into a file whenever you hit that error you should be able to spot circular references, if any. E.g., `var_dump()` will display `*RECURSION*`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yeah done that, it showed no message about recursion on it :\

Comment: If you save it in a reusable format (e.g. `serialize()`), can you encode it successfully when you check the log later? If that's the case, you might have hit an elusive PHP/7 bug...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'll try that. This is the current output I get ` array (
'ns' => 'user',
'where' => '{"_id":"MongoDB\\\\BSON\\\\ObjectID(5505a4f647ac1824618b4567)","status":10}',
'projection' =>
array (
),
'sort' =>
array (
),
'limit' => NULL,
'skip' => NULL,
)`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález done :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think this is a bug, everything else it works on, it is this specific array and only this array

Comment: What you showed in the post is not what the output of `var_dump()` looks like. Please try that function, because it can actually detect recursion.

Comment: @Andrea true that is var_export but interestingly it seem var_export doesn't like recursive references and fails on them http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php#75327 so if there was recursions I shouldn't be able to get that reponse at all

Comment: @Andrea though it seems it doesn't want to do it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON_ERROR_RECURSION` indicates that the data passed to `json_encode()` contains one or more recursive references.

```
$data = array();
$data['foo'] = &$data; // <-- recursive reference here

var_dump(json_encode($data)); // bool(false)
var_dump(json_last_error_msg()); // string(18) "Recursion detected"
var_dump(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_RECURSION); // bool(true)
```

Code like this will work though:

```
$data['foo'] = 'hello';
$data['bar'] = &$data['foo'];
```

But not like this (another recursive reference):

```
$data['foo'] = [1, 2, 3];
$data['foo'][] = &$data['foo'];
```

**Recursive reference means that the reference points to a variable that in turn contains the same reference again.**

Answer (score -1):

Most likely need to update mongodb driver (or maybe another extension). Extension with bug may write to shared memory (immutable arrays) - it is not allowed.

It is can be detected with `opcache.protect_memory` (http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.protect-memory)

http://news.php.net/php.internals/98210